# Blurred Desktop Background Image on Windows 7 Enterprise

Tags: windows-7, desktop, desktop-customization

I downloaded a few .jpg images with a resolution of 1440*900 (Same as the screen resolution of my desktop). However when I set it as desktop background it goes beyond the view and displays a blurred image. How do I ensure a good quality desktop background?

Answer (score 1):

In Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Personalization\Desktop Background 
Choose center as how you want your Desktop background to show up. This will make sure you can see what the image really looks like without altering it like fit, and stretch do.

The blurryness could be due to low dpi of the image.

Comment: How do i check whether the dpi is suitable for my desktop background with a screen resolution of 1440*900 ?

Comment: The DPI should at least be 72 to show up adequately on a computer.